# How to send update to a mobile app (Android & IOS)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I've a made a really basic [chat application](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Flash-Chat-Flutter-Complete.git)(no need to see the code)(from the course of Angela Yu, flutter)it is integrated with google firebase which uses firebase_core, firebase_auth & cloud_firestore packages for authentication and uploading chat data in cloud Firestore.

I've installed the app through debug.APK( **1. would it matter if it was release.APK?**) in my & my friend's phone both android ( let's take a neutral approach i.e the phone could be either IOS or Android).

What I aim is if I change my code( or we say update my app) I would want my app on both the phones to get updated( either automatically if possible or send a alert when user opens the app to update it), all this should be done with free of cost. **2. How can I achieve this in simplest manner?**. I know there is a standard way for this if the app was in Google play store or App store but I don't want to upload it on stores.

My guess for this is that we integrate our app with a server so that every time the app starts it checks for a update with the server and ask the user to update and gets updated. If this is achievable can someone please guide me with these two methods mentioned below:
**3(A). through free online server( can we use github or firebase?)

3(B). and can I make my own laptop as the server and code the app such that it doesn't need the server to be always online.( as in if my server is online it checks for update else it continues)**
**3(C). through paid servers ( just for information)**

**(4) Also please tell me why we chose cloud firestore over real time database for a chatting application?**

(I don't want to create a web app)

I've no idea how would any of this be achievable like nothing like what server would be used or is this even possible. So please help me with a detailed explanation on all( 1,2,3(A),3(B),3(c) ). Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Since you already use Cloud Firestore, consider creating a document in there with a field that contains the version number of the latest app release.

In your application code you then read this document upon startup, and check it against the app's own version. If the version from the database is newer, tell the user to upgrade.

You could even include instructions on where/how to get the latest version in the database too. That can come in really handy of you suddenly have to change your release mechanism in between versions.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response, After checking for update(through firestore) if there's a update available, it gives a alert to the user with a button to update the app, can you please guide me "how can I update the app after the user clicks on update" . My guess is I upload my latest .apk or .ipa on Google Drive(can I upload it on firebase?)so when user clicks on update button  the app automatically: 1. downloads the latest .apk  & 2.Opens the .apk file by itself and this way Android by default send a alert that "Do you want to install an update to this existing application"

Comment: I have no specific expertise there, but downloading the APK would be my go to approach.  On Firebase you could use either Hosting or Storage for that.

Comment: Please tell me if there's a better way to achieve the update? If not please tell me how can I achieve my mentioned method ( or please provide me with a flutter file manager resources). Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really appreciated!

Comment: Where would you recommend me downloading the latest .apk file for performing update in androids download folder or the app's support directory or somewhere else?